# Mounted device accessible per command line only after file manager

Tags: debian, samba, fstab, cifs

after hours of testing with `/etc/fstab`, I can finally reach my NAS shares with nautilus. However, I can't access the shares per command line (I use terminator on debian 10, NAS is configured with Ubuntu server 18). Only after clicking on the network share inside of nautilus, my terminal reconizes that there are files (i.e. per `ls`).

Does anyone can give me a hint, why I have (after PC startup) first to open nautilus, use my mouse and click on the network folder, before I can switch to my terminal and start working?

here is my fstab-line:
`//192.168.xxx.xxx/yyy /zzz cifs user,noauto,x-systemd.automount,username=???,password=???,_netdev 0 0`

Comment: After restarting, instead of using Nautilus, try running `sudo mount -a`; just want to see if your `/etc/fstab` entry is actually working.

Comment: @ajgringo619 doesn't `noauto` trump `mount -a`?

Comment: @steeldriver - good catch; didn't even see that! OP - remove the *noauto* switch and try again.

Comment: okay, nice. I removed `noauto` run `sudo mount -a` right after system start. And et voila: the mount point isnt empty. I think the next thing would be to execute sudo mount -a automatically...

Comment: That's already executed during startup. Removing `noauto` made it mount your NAS, so it should be present after reboot without any further action.